# advantages of access keys in webservices

Tags: web-services, security, rest, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I just read about how access keys and secret ids could be used to send authenticated requests to a RESTful webservice. However, I dont understand the advantages of using it over other alternatives(such as sending over the username and password, for instance), assuming that all communication with the server is over HTTPS.

What are the advantages of using such a mechanism?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Access key is roughly equivalent to a username, and access secret is roughly equivalent to a password. The access key makes it possible for the service to figure out who you are, and the access secret affirms that it's really you ("you" being your site in this context). The access key is not sensitive, and it is usually okay to be published in frontend code (Javascript, links in HTML, etc), while the access secret you need to keep, well, secret, because otherwise other people/sites will be able to impersonate your requests to the service. There is not much difference between key/secret and username/password scheme; the main difference is that key and secret are usually randomly generated by the service, which prevents people from using values like "default/12345" and similar nonsense.